# E/Volley: [839] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for

Tags: cakephp, rest

I bought an app template to mess around with, and when I'm trying to login in this case via Facebook it's calling the API I set up according to the guide.

It's calling

```
http://IP/mobileapp_api/api/registerUser
```

Now it's giving me the 404 error because the API folder does not exist, but when looking through the documentation and double-checking everything I also notice that he also doesn't have an API folder, but he's able to get a response just fine.

How is this possible?

Link for the video documentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1OTEbnD6CM&t=324s

I've tried to reach out to the developer, but with the current covid situation in his home country, I doubt I'll get a reply anytime soon, hence why I've come here.

Comment: Check how routes are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but uploading the files via CPanel and not Filezilla somehow made it all work.

Comment: If Filezilla skips hidden files, it would not have uploaded the `.htaccess`, which is pretty critical. Just a thought.